# Tunneling from Windows 10 to Jupyter (WebUI) running on AWS (Ubuntu) through Bastion using Putty

Tags: putty, tunnel, ssh-tunnel, jupyter-notebook

I know there are plenty of comments on questions similar to mine but **none** has a clear technical implementation of the solution.

The scenario is the following:
windows --> [bastion] --> jupyter (WebUI)

I would like to connect:
- from my local Windows browser
- using putty tunneling through the bastion
- to the private EC2 instance running Jupyter (WebUI)

Jupyter (WebUI) is accessible on port p.p.p.p:10000 which is only open to my bastion b.b.b.b.

My key files are "my_key.ppk" or "my_key.pem".

Please let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Do you want to tunnel HTTP?

Comment: I would like to use the browser of my local computer to connect through a bastion to a web UI on another ec2 machine. If this is tunnel HTTP then yes.

Comment: Jupyter is a webui so I thought is implicit. Isnt it?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Do you think is clear or how else do you suggest to improve my question? Thank you very much